# Google Maps Android API account ownership

Tags: android, google-maps

when getting an API key from Google on the Google Play Developer Console, they ask for an account on which you can enable/get API keys. If developing an application, should we use a personal account or make a proper account onto which enable this API Keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably good to use the same account you will use to publish your app in the Play Store, but I don't think it matters much if you use a different account.